# Where else can .Last hide? I deleted .Rprofile and .Last still runs

Tags: r, rprofile

I used to have a `dbConnect` statement as `.First` in my `.Rprofile` and a `dbDisconnect` statement as `.Last`. I no longer need these, so I removed them from `.Rprofile`, but R hangs when I exit because of the `dbDisconnect` statement. I can quit with `q(runLast=F)`.

```
> q()
Error in .Last() : could not find function "dbDisconnect"
```

I put an empty `.Rprofile` in my root, but I still get this error. I have the default `Rprofile.site`.

What causes this? Is there a fix? FWIW, I am on Windows 8.1 with R 3.3.1.

---

My `.Rprofile` is blank now. But it used to contain the [following](https://wrds-web.wharton.upenn.edu/wrds/support/Accessing%20and%20Manipulating%20the%20Data/_007R%20Programming/_001Using%20R%20with%20WRDS.cfm).

```
library(rJava)
.jinit(parameters="-Xmx8g")
library(RJDBC)

user <- "my_username"
pass <- '{SAS002}DBCC5712369DE1C65B19864C1564FB850F398DCF'

wrdsconnect <- function(user=user, pass=pass){
    drv <- JDBC("com.sas.net.sharenet.ShareNetDriver", "/usr/local/sas/jdbc_driver/sas.intrnet.javatools.jar",          identifier.quote="`")
    wrds <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:sharenet://wrds-cloud-h.wharton.private:8551/", user, pass)
    return(wrds)
}

.First <- function(){
    wrds <<- wrdsconnect(user=user, pass=pass)
}
.Last <- function(){
    dbDisconnect(wrds)
}
```

Comment: @ZheyuanLi -- It is blank now, but I can put the old version in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.Last` can also hide in `.Rdata`. My text editor opens R scripts in its program folder, where I had saved a work space with this `.Last`. Every time I opened R from a script in my text editor (my usual) it loaded this `.Last`.

No matter what you do to your `.Rprofile` and `Rprofile.site`, this will continue until you either delete this `.Rdata` or start in another directory.

Answer (score 1):

All the info your need is contained in `?Startup`.

You likely just deleted the home folder `.Rprofile` for the current user. Perhaps you want to search for a `Rprofile.site` file within the `/etc` directory of your program files.

```
file.path(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"), "etc", "Rprofile.site")
```